# Converting hours,minutes into seconds by parsing youtube t= queryparam in javascript/JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to parse the timestamp t= in youtube url("http://youtu.be/O4tzHn-EuHc?t=1h5m16s") and calculate the total number of seconds that i need to pass as a start parameter for embed youtube url "http://www.youtube.com/embed/XGSy3_Czz8k?start="

To get the hours, minutes and seconds i use reg-exp's as below. Let me know any improvement can be done in code to make it simple.

```
var url ="http://youtu.be/XGSy3_Czz8k?t=1h5m16s";
var timeStamp = url.match("t=(.)*?[&|(\s)]");
var hours = timeStamp[0].match(/(\d)+h/); 
var minutes = timeStamp[0].match(/(\d)+m/);
var seconds = timeStamp[0].match(/(\d)+s/);

var totalTimeInSeconds = 0;

if (hours) {
  hours = hours[0].replace("h","");
  totalTimeInSeconds += hours * 60 * 60;
}

if (minutes) {
    minutes = minutes[0].replace("m","");
    totalTimeInSeconds += minutes * 60;
}

if (seconds) {
   seconds = seconds[0].replace("s","")
   totalTimeInSeconds += seconds * 1;
}

console.log("hours:"+hours);
console.log("minutes:"+minutes);
console.log("seconds:"+seconds);
console.log("TotalTimeInSeconds:"+ totalTimeInSeconds);


<iframe width="420" height="345"
 src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/XGSy3_Czz8k?start="+totalTimeInSeconds>
 </iframe>
```

Comment: Did you know Moment.js ? It's the best plugin to manipulate dates without mind-breaking. Take a look http://momentjs.com/

Answer (score 1):

I think a good source for getting comments on your code would be [codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

You can get rid of your String.replace calls by slightly adjusting your regexes to read like this:

```
var hours = timeStamp[0].match(/(\d+)h/); 
var minutes = timeStamp[0].match(/(\d+)m/);
var seconds = timeStamp[0].match(/(\d+)s/);
```

With these regexes you will capture all digits at once, and can than use them like this:

```
if (hours) {
  totalTimeInSeconds += parseInt(hours[1], 10) * 60 * 60;
}

if (minutes) {
    totalTimeInSeconds += minutes[1] * 60;
}

if (seconds) {
   totalTimeInSeconds += seconds[1];
}
```

The use of `parseInt` is not necessary there,
but I'd probably introduce it to make it more explicit that conversion is taking place. I'd also suggest adjusting the regex for your `timeStamp` variable so that it already narrows down on the `t` parameter more.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var url ="http://youtu.be/XGSy3_Czz8k?t=1h5m16s";
    var timeStamp = url.match("t=(.)*?[&|(\s)]");
    timeStampSplitted = timeStamp[0].replace("t=","").replace("h", ":").replace("m", ":").replace("s", "").split(':');

    // minutes are worth 60 seconds. Hours are worth 60 minutes.
    var seconds = (+timeStampSplitted[0]) * 60 * 60 + (+timeStampSplitted[1]) * 60 + (+timeStampSplitted[2]);
```

Comment: This will fail when t=1h45s (hours, minutes, and seconds are all optional with YouTube timestamps).

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest is to use `RegExp` `replace` function:

```
var seconds = "1h5m16s".replace(/([0-9]+)h([0-9]+)m([0-9]+)s/, function(match, p1, p2 ,p3) {
  return p1 * 60 * 60 + p2 * 60 + p3 * 1
})
```

Note `p3 * 1` - it is a shortcut for `parseInt`. Also note that `replace` will return you a string - don't forget to convert to a number if needed.

Comment: This will fail when t=1h45s (hours, minutes, and seconds are all optional with YouTube timestamps).